# Setting DataGridViewRow.Height slow

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have noticed that setting row height in DataGridView control is slow. Is there a way to make it faster?

Answer (score 3):

What's caused similar layout delays for myself was related to
the **AutoSizeRowsMode** and **AutoSizeColumnsMode**

```
DataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = None
```

will likely fix it.

Also try **[ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columnheadersheightsizemode.aspx)** to None and **[AllowUserToResizeRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.allowusertoresizerows.aspx)** to False.

Answer (score 1):

If you can, try setting the height before you bind the control.

If you can't do that, try making the control hidden before setting the height.

Answer (score 0):

This works in most cases but I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for...

Try setting up the RowTemplate and use that to set the rows height.

```
        // my test to specify a size for a datagridview row
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name = "ColumnNameGoesHere" });
        dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height = 50;
        for (var x = 0; x <= 10000; x++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(x.ToString());
        }
```

Here is also a nice page on Windows Forms Programming
Best Practices for Scaling the Windows Forms DataGridView Control which you may find to be handy: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ha5xt0d9.aspx